# SLA of Network Availability in AWS servers and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

What is the network availability of AWS region. By this, I meant by what percentage of request will fail inside AWS. These requests are within private VPC inside AWS.

Please note I am saying failure due to network issue not due to server fault.

Is there any SLA that AWS provide for network availability?

Thanks,

Your reply will be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you actually experiencing a problem?  If so, you may want to provide more details, because there is no reason to expect that network failures would be anything but rare.

Comment: No, I am not facing any errors as such, but getting this information would help me take some design decision better. Like in case of failure what should be done. If network failures are frequent then, we would be more cautious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Lambda, since October 2018 AWS has introduced SLA for this service. In simplified terms, Lambda's SLA is 99.95%. For details, see this link:

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/sla

Comment: This means 99.95% which includes server faults and network faults. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, AWS VPC and Lambda do not provide external SLA on their availabilities. However, there are 3rd party tools (eg-  https://cloudharmony.com/status-group-provider) that measure the uptime for specific Cloud services (e.g., AWS EC2, AWS S3). Or you may refer to https://status.aws.amazon.com/ to get an idea about the current and previous health status of all AWS services.